# Postgresql: How do I use dynamic values when searching jsonb array of objects?

Tags: javascript, sql, database, postgresql

I am currently trying to build a query for finding specfic object within a jsonb array. I have the following query which works fine if I used a hard coded string for the "game" value e.g.

```
  const findGameQuery = `
        select playing
        from users
        where username = $1
        and playing @> '[{"game": "new-pokemon-snap"}]'
    `
```

However, if I use a dynamic value like I currently do for username, I get invalid json syntax error. e.g.

```
const findGameQuery = `
        select playing
        from users
        where username = $1
        and playing @> '[{"game": $2}]'
    `

    const { rows } = await query(findGameQuery, [username, game]);
    ctx.body = rows
```

How do I search using a dynamic value here? I have done a ton of searching and can't find any examples. $2 value is just a string so not sure why not accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you send this query, it only has ONE parameter:

```
select playing
from users
where username = $1
and playing @> '[{"game": $2}]'
```

The correct query is:

```
select playing
from users
where username = $1
and playing @> $2
```

You have to make the array with the object in the parameter.

```js
const gameObj = [{
    "game": game
}];
const gameParam = JSON.stringify(gameObj);
const { rows } = await query(findGameQuery, [username, gameParam]);
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for the explantion and clean code. By any chance do you know if its possible to just select the matching entry instead of whole table?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use parameters in a string literal.

Construct the `jsonb` object with PostgreSQL functions:

```
const findGameQuery = `
      select playing
      from users
      where username = $1
      and playing @> jsonb_build_array(jsonb_build_object('game', $2))
  `
```